# Creating a duplicate array

Tags: java, arrays

If I create a duplicate array like this in java is it correct ?

```
int [] array = { 10, 20 , 5 , 67 , 4} ;

int  [] d_array =  array ;
```

Comment: That's not a duplicate array; those are two variables referring to the same array.

Answer (score 3):

That's not creating a duplicate array. That's creating a new reference to an existing array. Modifying one will modify "both".

You want to look into the [System.arrayCopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method to create a new copied instance of some array.

Comment: Additional note: this works good for arrays of primitive and immutable object references because `System.arrayCopy` provides a shallow copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

See Kon's answer. Try this:

```
int [] array = new int[]{ 10, 20 , 5 , 67 , 4} ;

        int  [] d_array =  array.clone();
```

Now there are to different references

Comment: I would suggest using `System.arrayCopy()` instead of `clone()`. There are various drawbacks of clone. See Joshua Bloch's Effective Java for a summary of some reasons to prefer avoiding clone.

Comment: None of those reasons really apply to arrays, but there's also `Arrays.copyOf`, which is simpler to use than `arraycopy`.

Comment: Ok because on this question it should not matter what you use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179251/

Comment: Yes, you are both correct.

Answer (score 0):

in this case if you change any item in the first array it will be changed in the second, for example if you write:

```
array[0] = 5;
```

then also d_array[0] will become 5

to copy an array without having the same reference, replace:

```
int [] d_array = array ;
```

with

```
int [] d_array = array.clone();
```